# stdObject stored in database. How does one convert it to usable format?

Tags: database, table

So I logged on phpmyadmin, went to check out how data is stored in a table and saw it''s 'data' columns contents (pasted below):

`a:8:{i:2;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"label";s:6:"Vardas";s:5:"value";s:1:"A";}i:3;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"label";s:8:"Pavardė";s:5:"value";s:1:"G";}i:1;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"label";s:11:"El. paštas";s:5:"value";s:6:"verynicemail@email.com";}i:4;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Adresas";s:5:"value";s:1:"e";}i:5;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"label";s:8:"Tel. nr.";s:5:"value";s:1:"3";}i:6;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"label";s:7:"Mie";s:5:"value";s:7:"Vilnius";}i:7;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"label";s:5:"Ly";s:5:"value";s:7:"M";}i:8;O:8:"stdClass":2:{s:5:"label";s:11:"Gimimo data";s:5:"value";s:10:"2016-05-12";}}`

I know this is a std Object simply passed to the database table's row. How do I convert this data to a usable format (array or object)?

Or better else - what are the commands typically used in WP to store data in a database table's column, so I can find the plugin's source and edit it myelf.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [`unserialize()`](https://php.net/unserialize) it.

Be aware that most WordPress functions will automatically `unserialize()` database content before using it. See, for example, the **Used By** list for [`maybe_unserialize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/). This is by no mean an exhaustive list, I'm sure.

But if you're retrieving data directly from the database -- because there's not a WordPress function to achieve what you need to do -- you'll need to `unserialize()` the results.

For example:

```
$x = $wpdb->get_results( '{your SQL query}' );
// $x will be a serialized string
$unserialized_results = unserialize( $x );
```

The example you provide actually appears to be an array of 8 `stdObject`s, with keys from `1` to `8` (unless I'm reading it wrong, which is definitely possible). So that array would be what's in `$unserialized_results` at the end of my code snippet.

Comment: You must unserialize() it after actually pulling data with $wpdb->get_results() or, somehow, before?

Comment: After. I'll update my answer to reflect this.